# Move from xampp to Laravel Homestead: installation and opening projects

Tags: ssh, installation, project, homestead

I want to move two Laravel projects from xampp local environment to Homestead environment.

I followed laravel instructions, set up homestead and created a new project. However,getting an error message when trying to access ssh vagrant in the second homestead folder.

My new installed laravel project is in directory `C:\Projects\Project`

My homestead was installed in directory `C:\Users\tom\Projects_lar\Homestead`

For my first project I went to "vagrant ssh" through gitbash and created a new laravel project from there and automatically it appeared also in C:\Projects

Then I tried to git clone a second project after typing SSH vagrant, but the second project did not appear.

So then I created one more homestead and one more laravel project:

- C:\Projects\Project2
- C:\Users\tom\Projects_lar\Homestead2

Then I could run two laravel projects at the same time, but

I cannot access vagrant ssh in homestead2, it says:

> A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead' already exists.
>   Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
>   name, and try again.

I also tried to replace files inside `C:\Projects\Project` with files from my project in local xampp environment, but got an error:

```
! ) Warning: require(/home/vagrant/Project_lar/Project1/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/Project_lar/Project1/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
Call Stack
    Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0016  401952  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0049  402216  require( '/home/vagrant/Project_lar/Project1/vendor/autoload.php' ) .../index.php:24
3   0.0054  402896  ComposerAutoloaderInitf2c3bc37946cfa48d88d179975fa8f9f::getLoader( )    .../autoload.php:7
4   0.0077  407496  composerRequiref2c3bc37946cfa48d88d179975fa8f9f( )  .../autoload_real.php:56"*
```

I am not very good with virtual set ups yet. Questions:

- How should I set up 2 new laravel projects?
- How do I replace those two projects with my actual projects which currently I have in local xampp environment?

**Update:** I tried to edit project and project 2. It seems to be one and the same project, not two projects.

I am on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Homestead aims to be a singular virtual machine that allows you to develop all your projects. You do not need to create an entirely new vagrant box instance for every project, instead I would encourage you to use *shared folders*. Please see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#configuring-homestead).

Essentially, you are creating a folder that both the the host and the guest OS may use. The steps for adding a shared folder are as follows (explained in more depth in the docs as well):

Edit the `Homestead.yaml` and add your desired path, for example like so:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code/project  
      to: C:\Projects\project
```

Then you must run the command `vagrant --provision` in the homestead folder to let these changes take effect.